# Whats wrong with my code? (UIActionSheet)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

What's wrong with this code to create an UIActionSheet?
It is complaining about delegate:self, but I don't know why.
Here's my code:

```
-(IBAction)SocialButtonPressed:(id)sender{    
    UIActionSheet *social = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Share" 
                                                       delegate:self 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                         destructiveButtonTitle:@"Twitter" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Facebook", @"iMessage", @"Mail", nil];

    [social showInView:self.view];
}
```

Comment: What does it complain about?

Comment: I checked it, **worked wonderfully**. If you are not able to show it, check if you have hooked this action to button.

Comment: did you implement actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex: in self?

Answer (score 2):

Make your class conforming to that protocol:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <UIActionSheetDelegate>
```

Comment: it is not required at all.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya it is not required, but the compiler will return a warning if you don't do that. OP didn't specify what the compiler is complaining about, so it could be very well this.

Comment: I am not master in ios but i just copied the above code, and it works fine. And actionsheetDelegate is not added at all. XC4.6 plays with it

Comment: @AnoopVaidya if the delegate you are specifying does not conform to that protocol, you get a warning (@DrummerB is right)

Comment: Yes, but it works right?